How to Use WorkManager Plugin Version 0.6.x for Flutter?
I’m currently using the workmanager plugin for Flutter, and I’ve come across multiple references suggesting the use of version 0.6.x of the plugin for improved functionality and bug fixes. However, when I check pub.dev, the latest available version is 0.5.2.
How can I find or use version 0.6.x of the workmanager plugin? Is there a way to access pre-release versions, or has there been a delay in updating the official pub.dev listing?
Any guidance on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Context:
I’m using the workmanager plugin to schedule background tasks in my Flutter app, and I need some of the features and fixes mentioned in discussions about version 0.6.x. Specifically, I’m having issues with passing input data on iOS, and it seems this might be addressed in the newer versions.
Thank you!
I’ve already tried the following:
•   Checking the pub.dev page for the latest version
•   Looking for a GitHub repository or fork that might have the 0.6.x version


I am having the exact same issue!

In this commit, you can see when V6.0.X was added, maybe this can give more insight?
Added, this is the PR:
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/pull/511

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
